# Is there any MATLAB built-in function for feature extraction of single character?

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-extraction

I want to extract features of the characters that I have segmented, for pattern recognition using an SVM classifier. So is there any MATLAB built-in function for this problem. Please help.

Comment: What is the current representation of your characters? Greyscale pixel values? What kind of features are you looking for?

Comment: they are all in binary. i want maximum features for the recognition.